# Number of words if each word neither begins with G nor ends with S

Tags: permutations, combinations

Number of words that can be made with the letters of the word " GENIUS " if each word neither begins with G nor ends with S.

$(a)$ $24$

$(b)$ $240$

$(c)$ $480$

$(d)$ $504$

Are we supposed to make cases here like two letter word, three letter word and so on?

Is there any easier approach to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use *inclusion/exclusion* principle:

- Include the total number of words, which is $6!$
- Exclude the number of words starting with G, which is $5!$
- Exclude the number of words ending with S, which is $5!$
- Include the number of words starting with G and ending with S, which is $4!$

Hence the number of such words is $6!-5!-5!+4!=504$.

Comment: However, the only way someone could know that the exercise is not considering words that don't use all the letter, is that this would give a higher answer than any of the options ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yep. Same issue with regards to the fact that each letter can appear only once.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Oh, I just read the bottom of the question, I see (better) what you mean now. Yes, there are $504$ words with exactly $6$ letters. Since there is no higher option, we are bound to conclude that the question refers to $6$-letter words only.

Comment: Conventionnaly, in these exercises, without specifications, words are of any lenght from 1 to the max. It would be nice to compute for both options

Answer (score 0):

Let us first see total number of words formed with these 6 letters I.e 6!.

Now calculate

1. Total no. Of words starting with $G=5!$
2. Total no. Of words ending with  $S=5!$
3. Total no of words beginning with Great and ending with $S =4!$

To calculate words that neither begin with G nor ends with S consider that if we subtract total words by total words starting with G and ending with S then we'll get required answer.

So total number of words starting with G and ending with $S$ can be calculated as :-

Set of G_____ (words) +Set of S_____(words) - 
set of G____S(words).

Thus Ans is $6!-(5!+5!-4!)=504$.

Comment: What's the point of posting an answer identical to the accepted one after one year and a half?

Comment: Many won't get inclusion and exclusion principle so I thought to briefly explain each step. So I feel there is no harm explaining it again.